# Вызов модального окна fancybox 3 ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

Как вызвать модальное окно из скрипта? Сейчас я его вызываю по ссылке:

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="modal/login.html" href="javascript:;" data-options='{"touch" : false}'>Вход</a>
```

Мне нужно это все дело вызвать из js.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fancybox.open({
  src: 'modal/login.html',
  type: 'ajax'
});
```